# How to Solve TypeError str in Python

Tags: python, random

In the code I wrote in Python, TypeError str expression appears. The code I wrote is:

```
harfler = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","v","y","z","q","w","x"]
kackarakter = int(input("How Many Letters Do You Want ?:"))
print('("My WordPress Blog")', + random.choice(harfler) * kackarakter)
```

Result:
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
How Can I Solve?

Comment: You either need to remove the comma or the plus on the last line

Comment: remove the comma

Comment: What is the goal of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the print statement, try deleting the comma and only use + :

`print('("My WordPress Blog")' + random.choice(harfler) * kackarakter)`

Comment: I removed the comma but the following error comes up:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str